# What happened in the Ropsten hardfork from Byzantium to Constantinople?

Tags: consensus, hardforks, byzantium, constantinople

What were the consensus issues during the Constantinople hardfork in the Ropsten testnet?

One [noted consensus issue](https://notes.ethereum.org/4Ta9WZJ8Qta5z1HYQB4UiA) is:

> `geth` and `parity` have been in noticeable disagreement regarding block
>   4230605. The discrepancy is gas-used in this transaction - parity charged 791587, geth charged 1078987.

Why did they disagree? Were there other consensus issues?

Comment: This is an ongoing issue but deserves to be well documented when it is resolved. This comment will be deleted afterwards. Please do not post hasty answers. Thanks :)

Comment: There's an explanation here https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17906#issuecomment-429917337

Comment: @eth any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem have been solved over [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17906)

Quoting nicksavers here

> The thing is that if you did a fast-sync of `Geth >1.8.17` after the
> fork at `block 4230605`, it would have probably skipped the check on
> that block and assume it's correct based on proof of work.... then
> break on `4238641`. Similarly, if you start **fast-sync** now, you'll skip
> fully verifying that block... etc. (explanation here)

> The cause was apparently an implementation detail of `EIP-1283`. Parity
> kept track of the refund inside each call, but defined it '**unsigned**',
> which made it impossible to become **negative**
>
> The solution discussed as of this moment is to use the interpretation
> of Geth. Parity has already solved the issue on their side with an
> update ([openethereum/openethereum#9746](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum/pull/9746)). Miners will start mining on
> the Geth Constantinople chain on Ropsten to make sure it becomes the
> canonical chain. The Parity update should be able to follow it. If
> another conflict arises, it will be dealt with at that time.
>
> Progress should be posted on notes, but it's a little bit behind on
> the latest information.

Since the error had been solved. But if you are facing this issue please re-sync your node from the start.